# how to create a banner in Magento 2.2.4 cant find the banner tab

Tags: magento2.2.4

Does the Magento 2.2.4 have a tab for banner creation through admin panel
how exactly do I create a banner in Magento 2.2.4. Can't I seem to find the banner tab here?

Comment: Magento 2, not provide any basic module for the banner, but you can do by adding the custom module or you can do by adding some new JS in front Theme and banner HTML in CMS Block.

Comment: Ok, how do i add the custom module please

Comment: Kunj, what is the difference between cms page link ,  cms static block and catalog category link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get free extensions from [here](https://marketplace.magento.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=banner%20slider#q=banner%20slider&idx=m2_cloud_prod_default_products&p=0&fR%5Bext_platform%5D%5B0%5D=Magento%202&nR%5Bprice.USD.default%5D%5B%3C%3D%5D%5B0%5D=0&nR%5Bvisibility_search%5D%5B%3D%5D%5B0%5D=1&is_v=1). You will need to place the order with 0 Price.

Answer (score 0):

**In Magento 2.x you need to Integration of the Block in to CMS**

- Go to the Admin Panel of the Magento Store and navigate to the
  Content tab from the left corner of the page. Next, click the Blocks
  option.
- Add New Block.
- Add the details of the Block. Enter the Block Title (Title of the
  Block) and Block Identifier (Id of the Block).

You could add the Block in the content section by using this shortcode:

```
{{block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" block_id="Banner_View"}}
```

This will help you out. [Here](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/customize-homepage-of-magento-2/)